# Where in the code of this unstake function is ETH actually transferred?

Tags: solidity, ether, solidity-0.8.x, function, code

I am looking at this repo, which is contracts for a decentralized pegged asset issuance system backed by liquid staking tokens like rETH. Specifically, I have a question about the functions ***unstake*** in contracts/bridges/BridgeRETH.sol and ***unstakeETH*** in contracts/facets/BridgeRouterFacet.sol, which allow you to remove your rETH from the system and get ETH back. ***unstakeEth*** calls ***unstake***

My question is, where in these functions does it specify that ETH should actually be sent to the wallet that called them? I know when you, say, call a deposit function, you include the ETH with your call, basically, so you want see something in the code that says ETH is being transferred. But here we start with rETH.

[Here is a link to the repo](https://github.com/Cyfrin/2023-09-ditto)

Answer (score 3):

The `BridgeRouterFacet` contract's `unstakeETH()` function:

```js
 function unstakeEth(address bridge, uint88 zethAmount)
        external
        nonReentrant
        onlyValidBridge(bridge)
    {
        if (zethAmount == 0) revert Errors.ParameterIsZero();

        uint88 fee = zethAmount.mulU88(bridge.unstakeFee());

        uint256 vault;
        if (bridge == rethBridge || bridge == stethBridge) {
            vault = Vault.CARBON;
        } else {
            vault = s.bridge[bridge].vault;
        }

        if (fee > 0) {
            zethAmount -= fee;
            s.vaultUser[vault][address(this)].ethEscrowed += fee;
        }
        uint88 ethAmount = _ethConversion(vault, zethAmount);
        vault.removeZeth(zethAmount, fee);
        IBridge(bridge).unstake(msg.sender, ethAmount);
        emit Events.UnstakeEth(bridge, msg.sender, zethAmount, fee);
    }
```

Like you pointed out, this function calls `unstake()` with `msg.sender` here:

`IBridge(bridge).unstake(msg.sender, ethAmount);`

And then in the `BridgeRETH` contract's `unstake` function:

```js
 function unstake(address to, uint256 amount) external onlyDiamond {
        IRocketTokenRETH rocketETHToken = _getRethContract();
        uint256 rethValue = rocketETHToken.getRethValue(amount);
        uint256 originalBalance = address(this).balance;
        rocketETHToken.burn(rethValue);
        uint256 netBalance = address(this).balance - originalBalance;
        if (netBalance == 0) revert NetBalanceZero();
        (bool sent,) = to.call{value: netBalance}("");
        assert(sent);
    }
```

You can see the ETH being transferred in this line:

`(bool sent,) = to.call{value: netBalance}("");`

`call` is a global method in **Solidity** that allows you to interact with other addresses by sending data and/or `ETH`.

You can learn more about `call` [here](https://medium.com/@solidity101/100daysofsolidity-understanding-the-call-function-in-solidity-interacting-with-contracts-4ccd216b1dfe#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9Ccall%E2%80%9D%20function%20in%20Solidity%20enables%20contract%2Dto%2D,certain%20considerations%20and%20potential%20pitfalls.), [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/call/), and [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/.).